# Dealing/resolving NullReferenceExceptions in ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, nullreferenceexception

I have a WPF/C# application that is using the MVVM light framework.  When it renders some of the pages, however, a couple of the fields in one of the viewModels are being accessed before the View initializes, which results in NREs.

I've been using the simple solution of adding statements in the getters akin to `if (obj==null) return new object();` which seems to fix the NRE, but this doesn't seem like it's a very good solution to me.  Is there a better way to go about resolving this situation?

Comment: Can you expand a little on what's being accessed and when? For example, is this in the viewmodel constructor? Binding errors fail fairly silently, so if you're getting NREs you can probably catch it in the debugger and see the callstack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, you described looks like [Null Object design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). If you don't want create new objects for every getter, you can use singleton instance for that:

```
public sealed class NullObject {
    public static readonly NullObject Default = new NullObject();
    public static object GetNotNull( object value ) {
        return object.ReferenceEquals( value, null ) ? (object)Default : value;
    }
}
//....
private object someField;
public object SomeProperty {
    get { return NullObject.GetNotNull( this.someField ); }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a much more light weight solution that I'm going to look into implementing, Thanks! I just want to make sure, though: creating new objects for every getter is technically a correct solution to this problem that won't create any adverse side effects?

Comment: Creating new instance of object has no side effect, but it costs more resources than using one instance. However if you use special class for NOT-NULL value (NullObject), you can check for it in code, so you can know if returned value is fake.